# Spree action require_login creates a redirect loop when assigned to the before_action filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

I am trying to restrict the entire Spree (Rails) app so that only users who are logged in can access the site. I read in the rails documentation that

> If a "before" filter renders or redirects, the action will not run

Here is the code from app/controllers/application_controller.rb that is causing this loop

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :require_login

  private

  def logged_in?
     spree_current_user != nil
  end

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = spree_current_user
      # supposed to halt request cycle - 
      # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters
      redirect_to spree_login_path 
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: If you're getting a redirect loop it's likely because you don't have anything to not redirect someone on the login page. Visitor goes to root, they're not logged in, they get redirected on the login page. Then on the login page, they're not logged in so they get redirected to the login page. Repeat forever.

Comment: according to the [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters), a redirect inside a before_action is supposed to halt the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work without rendering a custom page by changing the placement of `skip_before_action`. According to the rails documentation that you linked to:

> In this example the filter is added to ApplicationController and thus
>   all controllers in the application inherit it. This will make
>   everything in the application require the user to be logged in in
>   order to use it. For obvious reasons (the user wouldn't be able to log
>   in in the first place!), not all controllers or actions should require
>   this. You can prevent this filter from running before particular
>   actions with skip_before_action:
>
> ```
> class LoginsController < ApplicationController   
>    skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:new, :create] 
> end
> ```

This means that the `skip_before_action` should go in your LoginsController and not your ApplicationsController. I was able to get it to work by making this split:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login

  private

  def logged_in?
    spree_current_user != nil
  end

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "Please Login or Sign Up"
      redirect_to spree_login_path
    end
  end
end
```

Then I used a [controller decorator](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/logic.html) to add the `skip_before_action` to the sessions_controller:

```
Spree::UserSessionsController.class_eval do
  skip_before_action :require_login

end
```

You may need to add decorators and the `skip_before_action` to other controllers that are affecting login and you want users to have access to (like password resets and registrations)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I used `skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:spree_login]` to stop the redirect loop, and also created a static page to point users to when they are not logged in (log in portal)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  require 'createsend'

  before_action :require_login
  skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:spree_login]

  private

  def logged_in?
     spree_current_user != nil
   end

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "Please log in to access the Wholesaler site."

      render('staticpage/wholesale_login')
    end
  end

end
```

It is still unclear to me why my original `redirect` inside `before_action` was not halting the redirect loop as the [rails documentation suggests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters), but I had to get this working somehow. Thank you Antarr and gmacdougall for your help.